# Data not saving after changing it

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am using a listbox to display my data in textboxes and combos. When I change the data it does not save in my table and just can not work out why.

I have attached a simple copy of the database so you get an idea of what im doing

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qkndka198tmqc62/Database7.accdb?dl=0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

Your form is bound to the table test_table; You display data into a bunch of bound fields by clicking on an item in the listbox - but you're never changing the current record of the table, and thus you always update the first record, with whatever values are currently displayed.

Instead of using the listbox, use the navigation buttons the form enables to get to the record you want to update, then your sample may work.

Alternatively If you added ID to listbox's rowsource, when you wanted to save you could do something like:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Test_Table SET [Business Area] = '" & Combo2 & "' WHERE ID = " & List8.Column(4)
```

Better still, (in addition to the above) unbind the form & the controls, and use a recordset to display the current values of the fields onto the form when a record is selected in the listbox. Then the data doesn't need to be in the listbox's rowsource, so you'd change the rowsource to "SELECT ID, Dates FROM Test_Table" and set the columnwidths property to "0cm;3cm" to hide the ID from the display. Then any reference to List8 is a reference to the ID of the current record, and

```
List8 = 4
```

Will set the selected index of List8 to the row with ID = 4.

Then after saving, you can

```
List8.Requery
List8 = 4
List8_Click
```

will re-display the data from the database.

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for the help. Unfortunately still cant get this to work. I am using this record set: Dim db As Database
Dim rec As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tbl_ComplaintsCoded")

rec.Edit
rec("Business Expert") = Me.Text5
rec.Update
Me.List1.Requery